# name not existing in current context c# form

Tags: c#, winforms

```
label9.AutoSize = true;
label9.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
label9.Font = new Font("Microsoft Yi Baiti", 13.2000008F, FontStyle.Italic, GraphicsUnit.Point);
label9.ForeColor = Color.DimGray;
label9.Location = new Point(28, 354);
label9.Name = "label9";
label9.Size = new Size(134, 23);
label9.TabIndex = 40;
label9.Text = "Phone Number";
label9.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
label9.Click += (label9_Click); //error here
```

there is an error on the last line saying the name doesnt exist

can someone please tell me why there is an error there? ive tried creating a controls line but the error was still there also i made this on [design] on vs so im not sure where i went wrong especially because im new to c# and visual studio. am i using the click event wrong?

Comment: Do you have an event handler named `label9_Click` defined? [How to handle a control event (Windows Forms .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-add-an-event-handler?view=netdesktop-7.0)

Comment: _Don't edit the designer.cs file!_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you've probably edited the name of the function in your form code, and not set it to the new name for the listener in `Designer.cs`.

As the others have said, you really shouldn't manually edit the `Designer.cs` file. That is automatically handled by the design tab of your form.

Safest way would be remove the control and add it back again, then double click it and it will create the necessary code for you.

If you do want to fix it quickly by editing the `Designer.cs` file (which I wouldn't really recommend):

```cs
this.label9.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label9_Click);
```

And then in your main code window for the form add this method:

```cs
private void label9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation that really helped me understand what waas going on and now its working

i didnt intentionally  edit the designer.cs but it as there was an error i went onto it to see where i went wrong

Comment: @boshbosh no worries, happy to help! Just remember that those files are linked. If you want to change the name of a method then you should do a refactor on it so it changes all references as well in the project. That way you can avoid these sorts of issues in the future

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the error line
2. Open the Form designer
3. Double click `label9`

These steps will create the required handler:

```
private void label9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to remove the wrong line. Then open the form designer and double click on label9. VS creates appropriate event handler for you. You need only to fill it with your code.